# Match first column of two files and Merge last column of File2 in File1 in linux

Tags: text-processing

I have a problem and it might be a dumb one but I can not get hold of it. I know it is very simple to match columns from files and merge the files but unfortunately even after trying so many commands i can not reach my goal.

I have 2 files

File1:

```
BP2808  1.83684448966078    10.7449438228544    27.7057862093578    1.4123961881793E-07 4.26390957350344E-06
BP1319  2.75272032616902    8.74039675296892    27.5666097653874    1.51776372331745E-07    4.46142652354102E-06
dps 1.47015471230894    10.7061416142689    27.1494663323484    1.88317176247083E-07    5.39359707353824E-06
fusA    -1.38504972563843   11.8361844791496    27.0016273796008    2.03284239943838E-07    5.67671240043168E-06
BP1320  2.67552497792458    8.77604324182685    26.5184193030292    2.61037278592442E-07    7.11167415092092E-06
```

And the second file with 2 columns

File2:

```
BP2808  hypothetical protein
BP1319  Memebrane protein
dps     DNA-binding protein
fusA    elongation factor G
```

Desired output:

```
BP2808  1.83684448966078    10.7449438228544    27.7057862093578    1.4123961881793E-07 4.26390957350344E-06    hypothetical protein
BP1319  2.75272032616902    8.74039675296892    27.5666097653874    1.51776372331745E-07    4.46142652354102E-06     Memebrane protein
dps 1.47015471230894    10.7061416142689    27.1494663323484    1.88317176247083E-07    5.39359707353824E-06     DNA-binding protein
fusA    -1.38504972563843   11.8361844791496    27.0016273796008    2.03284239943838E-07    5.67671240043168E-06    elongation factor G
BP1320  2.67552497792458    8.77604324182685    26.5184193030292    2.61037278592442E-07    7.11167415092092E-06    NA
```

I have tried awk, paste. join but do not get the desired output, i guess it is because of the spaces between strings in the last column of file 3, if i am not wrong.

```
paste File1 File2 | awk '{$2=""; print}' > Testing

awk -F\t '{getline f1 <"File1" ;print f1,$2}' OFS=, File2 > Testing

join -t'\t' <(sort File1) <(sort File2) > Testing
```

and many more after searching a lot on the internet. If someone could help me it would save a lot of my time.

Comment: Are the files tab-delimited or space-delimited? We cannot see ...

Comment: I do not know how to use the double escape and the files are tab-delimited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
join -t $'\t'
```

`join` doesnt interpret backspace escaped special characters. `\t` will literally stay `\t` (this does not equal the tab character), much the same like `echo '\t'` vs `echo -e '\t'` (`join` behaves like `echo` without `-e` ). So, you have to let shell interpret the character using [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) `$'...'`.

---

`awk` *will* interpret special characters, so you can use:

```
awk -F'\t'
```

but not

```
awk -F\t
```

However, you could use `\\t` to let the shell interpret the `\\`, but in my opinion quotes are more readable ...

For the latter command, `\t` will be interpreted by the shell to just `t` (Try: `echo \t`). Quote it, so the shell does not interpret it.

Comment: thank you very much the join works now :)